# Converting INT to HEX string using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Looking to convert an integer to the hex string equivalent using TSQL

```
1 =    1
10 =   A
100 = 64
1000 = 3E8
```

etc.

SO FAR the solution seems to be

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @str = sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(VARBINARY, @num))
IF @num < 16
   SELECT @str = RIGHT(@str, 1)
ELSE IF @num < 256
   SELECT @str = RIGHT(@str, 2)
ELSE IF @num < 4096
   SELECT @str = RIGHT(@str, 3)
ELSE -- and so on
   SELECT @str = RIGHT(@str, 4)

RETURN @str
```

but someone this seems a little klutzy, is there a better way ?

Comment: @IlyaBursov, this Q is for int to hex STRING, that too WITHOUT 0x or the leading ZEROS

Comment: just look at other solutions on link I've provided

Comment: @IlyaBursov already did that, they don't address part 2 of this question, the klutzy one !

Comment: check `SELECT dbo.ToHex(4095) --> FFF
CREATE FUNCTION ToHex(@value int)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @seq char(16)
    DECLARE @result varchar(50)
    DECLARE @digit char(1)
    SET @seq = '0123456789ABCDEF'

    SET @result = SUBSTRING(@seq, (@value%16)+1, 1)

    WHILE @value > 0
    BEGIN
     SET @digit = SUBSTRING(@seq, ((@value/16)%16)+1, 1)

     SET @value = @value/16
     IF @value  0 SET @result = @digit + @result
    END 

    RETURN @result
END
GO` this is from link above